# Google Cloud App Engine download object from Google Cloud Storage issue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am hosting a CodeIgniter based PHP web application on Google App Engine flex environment.

I am able to allow the user to upload data like images, video to my Google Cloud  Storage bucket. But what I need to do is when the image or video gets uploaded to the storage, at that same time the same object should be downloaded on Google  App Engine server's source code.

i.e. There should be a copy of the uploaded image on my current App Engine source code server (App Engine current instance).

Comment: That's highly impossible, due to how App Engine works. You could try to do something like this: every time an user uploads something, a message is sent via Pub/Sub, and your instances receive this message, and download this file. Even with that, it's highly discouraged, since instances in App Engine come and go. Maybe your app is more suited for a normal, regular, Compute Engine instance.

Comment: What do you mean downloaded on Google App Engine server's source code?

Comment: Because of the scalability features of Google App Engine, whatever solution you'd come up with to transfer the data from Google Cloud Storage (and the moment in which can happen would be right after upload time with the help of https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) you'd need to take into account the number of instances running at that moment which at first seems like a design flaw. If you're only worried with having copies of the data then transfering it to yet another bucket would solve the issue. Can you provide a use case that motivates your question?